# Proofs involving vector spaces and linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

In  this problem, $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces, $T: V \rightarrow W$ is a linear transformation, and $X$ is a finite set of vectors in $V$. Prove the following three statements:

(a) If $X$ is linearly independent and $T$ is one-to-one, then $T(X)$ is linearly independent.
(b) If $X$ spans $V$ and $T$ is surjective, then $T(X)$ spans $W$.
(c) If $X$ is a basis for $V$ and $T$ is bijective, then $T(X)$ is a basis for $W$.

I don't want the answer, I would like to do most of it myself. I would just like some guidance on how to start or approach these. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

a) Choose nonzero scalars from your field and vectors from $T(X)$ such that $a_1\vec {Tv_1} + \cdots + a_n \vec {Tv_n} =0$. We aim to show this is impossible. Thus we have $T(a_1 \vec v_1 + a_n \vec v_n) = 0$. Since $T$ is one-to-one its kernel is null, therefore $a_1 \vec v_1 + a_n \vec v_n = 0$, which implies that $a_1 = \cdots = a_n = 0$.  Therfore $T(X)$ is independent.

b) Since $T$ is surjective, let $\vec{Tv} \in W$. We wish to find a vector $\sum_1^n a_i \vec v_i$ with $v_i \in X$ such that $\vec{T(\sum_1^n a_i \vec v_i)} = Tv$.  As the $X$ spans $V$ just choose a linear combination of vectors $\vec v_i$ from $X$, $\sum_1^n a_i \vec v_i$, such that $\sum_1^n a_i \vec v_i = \vec v$.  This proves the claim.

c) If $T$ is bijective, then we have that the conclusions from parts $a$ and $b$ hold. Namely, $T(X)$ spans $W$ and $T(X)$ is linearly independent.  But this means exactly that $T(X)$ is a basis for $W$.

Comment: He was asking for guidance, not the answer...

Comment: You're right.           .

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question you basically need to use just the definitions. Here are some hints. Let $X=\{x_1,\dots,x_m\}$.

(a) $X$ is linearly independent means: if $a_1x_1+\dots +a_mx_m=0$ then $a_1=a_2=\dots =a_m=0$. You want to prove that if $a_1T(x_1)+\dots +a_mT(x_m)=0$ then $a_1=a_2=\dots =a_m=0$. To prove that you need to use linearity of $T$ and the fact that $T$ is one-to-one.

(b) $X$ spans $V$ means: for any $v\in V$ there exist scalars $a_1,\dots, a_m$ such that $v=a_1x_1+\dots+a_mx_m$. You want to prove that for any $w\in W$ there exist scalars $a_1,\dots, a_m$ such that $w=a_1T(x_1)+\dots+a_mT(x_m)$. Again, use linearity and surjectivity.

(c) Combine the conclusions of (a) and (b).